# Performance issue when multiple columns of same table are grouped

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, stored-procedures, ssms

I am dealing with large amount of data approx 1 million rows with 100s of columns.
I have this proc which performs some calculation over this data based on grouped by a **colum1**.

Now the same calculation is performed over this data grouped by  column1, **column2**.

I can optimise the whole operation by creating indexes on column1 and **column2**.
But how i can achive the performance if **column1** or **column2** are dynamic and up to nth column.

Example:
For n columns the group by operation is going to be like as follows

operation 1 : group by column1
Operation 2 : group by column1, column2

Operation n : group by column1, column2..... upto columN

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all those aggregates at once use [ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to calculate multiple aggregate grains in a single scan.

If you want to optimize a large table for many different aggregates use a [Columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) index.

Comment: This looks promising. I will look into this. Thanks